# Arquillian-Jboss Wildfly Persistence unit error

Tags: wildfly-10, arquillian-drone

I'm new to arquillian and wildfly , the thing is that i'm trying to run an `EAR`, that contains a `jar` and `war` , on arquillian and using wildfly

I'm having this error `"WFLYJPA0038: Failed to add persistence unit service for SimbaPersistance"
..
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.persistenceunit."0-snecma-simbav2-ear-module.ear#SimbaPersistance".__FIRST_PHASE__ is already registered`

I have already added the `persistence.xml` file to the ear using arquillian and set up the standalone-full and the `jboss-resources-ds` xmls

thank you all in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution , for those who have the same bug

-i had to remove the persistence.xml from everywhere in the ear

-add the persistence.xml to a jar and, add that jar in the root of the ear so that the persistence will be accessible for every recource in the ear

Answer (score 0):

Please review the tag deployments of the file standalone.xml of your server wildfly and erase de tag deployment where is your project name, then make the Maven build